# How to scale or fit header texts in Powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Good day,

I am making a report DataWindow when it is previewed the rightmost columns spill to the next page. So, is there a way to dynamically fit them according to paper size of the datawindow?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `datawindow.zoom` DW property to reduce the size until everything fits on a page, but AFAIK there is no automatic adjustment.

You can experiment in runtime by putting the DW in print preview mode `dw.modify("datawindow.print.preview='yes'` to see how your data will fit on a page.

BTW, the `datawindow.zoom` setting is only for display (in normal or preview mode) and not for printing.

Answer (score 0):

If the field containing the column headings is only a single line you could expand it so that the information 'word wraps'.